# Looking for comic where Spider-Man faces a lawsuit over him leaving his webs everywhere

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, spider-man

If I am not wrong, the earlier Spider-Man comics had him use only his webs for transportation. Later on though, when he got his Spider-Cycle, he almost abandoned using his webs for transportation altogether.

I am looking for this comic in which I **think** Spider-Man faces a lawsuit over his leaving his sticky webs everywhere.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about the comic? What year did you read it? What year do you think it was released? Was there a traditional villain or just focus on the web littering?

Comment: Spider-Man is grumbling about being issued a citation for littering in [Web of Spider-Man Vol.1 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Annual_Vol_1_2). - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkSFh.png

Comment: You may try looking in TVTROPES WARNING https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HeroInsurance

Comment: @fez, I have a hazy memory on this topic. I only read a couple frames and got distracted by something else.

Comment: @Valorum, nice find! But I am pretty sure that he faces a lawsuit, not just him getting a ticket.

Comment: A few questions: Is the Spider-cycle relevant here, I mean the web issue was about his normal webs or spider-cycle webs? Second, which Spider are you referring to: Peter or Miles? Lastly, any notes about the art, time when you read it, any other things that can help us find the proper story arc?

Comment: @Shreedhar, First off, I mean his normal webs. The ones he used for slinging around anyway. I refer to Peter here, as I think it was him that I read about, but I couldn't be too sure. Like I mentioned in a n above comment, I have an extremely hazy memory about when or where I read it. I will hazard a guess that the drawing technique was old like in the comic patch that was referred to in Valorum's comment above.

Comment: Don't the webs dissolve after a time anyway.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt, I am pretty sure they didn't dissolve when this comic was released.

Comment: Spider-man and Ice Man received a citation from a fat American-Irish cop in 'Spider-Man and his Amazing Friends' episode one for building an ice slide in Central park

Comment: @Valorum, can you please share any screenshots of the same? I think this is something similar to what I read.

Comment: I'm sure spidey has the nous to develop bio-degradable webs tech...

Comment: Heh, https://screenrant.com/spiderman-sued-himself-accidentally-she-hulk-marvel-comics/

Comment: @Infinity Milestone - In the mainstream (Earth-616) comics, it was stated that Spider-Man's webs evaporate after an hour as early as _[Amazing Spider-Man Annual #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Annual_Vol_1_1)_ in 1964. He later stated in _[Amazing Spider-Man #18](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_18)_ that it might take him months of lab work to make it permanent, which suggests he'd never created a formula for permanent webbing, and that he was using evaporating webbing from the start.

Comment: @LogicDictates, yikes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #297](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_297)*, Spider-Man accidentally webbed up a civilian while testing out a new pair of web-shooters, leading said civilian to threaten him with a lawsuit.

Not sure if this is what you had in mind though, as Spider-Man wasn't accused of leaving his webs everywhere, and was never actually sued, just *threatened* with a lawsuit.

[image: Three comic panels showing Spider-Man perched on the side of a building, firing a spray of webbing from his right web-shooter, and that webbing inadvertently landing on a man walking his dog on the street below. The man angrily yells up at Spider-Man, calling him a moron, a maniac, a menace.]

[image: A single comic panel showing Spidey apologising to the man, and telling him that the webbing will dissolve in about an hour, while swinging away. The man, who is stuck to the spot by the webbing, tells Spider-Man he'll sue him.]

Comment: this is the ONE! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Spider-Man and Iceman received a citation from a police officer for leaving an ice slide in Central Park in the first episode of *[Spider-Man and his Amazing Friends](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_and_His_Amazing_Friends_Season_1_1)*.

[image]

Firestar resolves the situation by flying over the slide and melting it.

[image]

Comment: Great, now they can be fined for flooding the place.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the pics! I see what you are saying and this IS quite near but @ LogicDictates' answer is what I was looking for. Thanks anyway for trying!

Comment: @InfinityMilestone - That's fine. A wrong answer *for you* might be a right answer for someone else who comes looking!